# Expected amount of tries to be made until success

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

lets say I have something (guessing a byte) that occurs with the probability of $\frac{1}{2^8}$. So when I guess once, the probability of me guesing the byte right is $\frac{1}{2^8}$. I know that I can compute (as a sum of binomial probabilites $P[X=1]+P[X=2]+\dots+P[X=n]=1-P[X=0]$, where $P[X=i]=\binom{n}{i}(\frac{1}{2^8})^i(1-\frac{1}{2^8})^{n-i}$) the probability of me succeding at guessing the byte right in $n$ tries.

But I am having trouble figuring out if there exists a way of me calculating the average number $n$ of tries I have to make to guess it correctly. Is my question nonsense? I know I can say that with $n$ tries the probability of me being right is $0.5$ for example, but is there anything else I can calculate? Something like an expected value but I dont know how to define my random variable in that way.

Comment: The fancy name for the random variable you want (to take the expectation of) is a stopping time or hitting time.  It can be modeled as a Markov chain using an absorbing state (or states) for the successful outcome.

Comment: Sounds like this is related to the negative hypergeometric distribution, assuming that you are guessing "without replacement."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you can tell your guess is right or wrong before the next guess and you can stop guessing once you guess correctly.

Then the number of trials until success is [Geometric Random Number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution)
Since you stop when you get it right, you failed $x-1$ times and one success at $x^{\text{th}}$ trial.

---

Edit.
It might not the one you are looking for. 
It is because the Geometric Random number has a fixed success probability. 
In your example case, you don't guess the byte which was wrong.
It is like Geometric without replacement.

We may use [Negative hypergeometric random](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_hypergeometric_distribution)

$$N=2^8, K=2^8-1, r=1$$

Here we have to stop when $r$ failure occur. We have to set a wrong guess as a success and correct guess as a failure.

X: How many wrong guesses until correct guess.

But the number of trials until correct guess $= X+1 $ because we have to count the trial of correct guess.

Mean would be $\frac{2^8-1}{2}+1= \frac{2^8+1}{2}$

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for!

Comment: I edited my answer. It might not that simple.